# If I draw an enemy that is discarded because it cannot spawn, do I draw another encounter?

Tags: arkham-horror-card-game

During the Mythos phase when each investigator draws an encounter card, if an enemy is drawn that spawns at a particular location that hasn't yet entered play, that card is discarded.

Do I then draw another encounter card in that situation, or did my investigator simply benefit from the lucky draw?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the situation where no location in play is a viable place to spawn the monster, then you have lucked out and the card is discarded without drawing a replacement card.

From the [rules reference](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/c4/b0/c4b0d66c-d79e-411b-bdb5-b5d8c457d4bc/ahc01_rules_reference_web.pdf) (page 19 under **Spawn**):

> If an enemy has no legal location to spawn at (for example, if its spawn instruction directs it to a specific location that is not in play, or if no location in play satisfies its “spawn” instruction), it does not spawn, and is discarded instead.

Nowhere in the rules does it state that a replacement card should be drawn for the discarded monster.